# What is the difference between ulimit -r and -e?

Tags: shell, priority, ulimit, real-time

What is the real-time scheduling priority mean (ulimit -e) ,and how to use it ?

```
-r     The maximum real-time scheduling priority
-e     The maximum scheduling priority ("nice")
```

Comment: Uh...  as currently written, the question indicates that real-time scheduling is -e, but the quoted text indicates that is -r.

Comment: What OS are you using?